# Pivot and Null Value

Tags: t-sql

In this simple Pivot Example (T-SQL), I am trying to replace the NULL with 0. I have tried all the suggestions that I found but still getting NULL. How do I replace the NULL value in a PIVOT with 0

```
select *
from 
 (
       select ISNULL([vendid],0)as [vendid],isnull(origdocamt,0)as origdocamt 
        from APDoc
 ) X
pivot
(sum(origdocamt) for vendid in ([AAA],[BBB])) As P
```

Output

---

AAA BBB

45800   NULL

Comment: Maybe try sum(ISNULL(origdocamt,0)) or SELECT AAA, ISNULL(BBB,0)  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use `IsNull` or `Coalesce` to perform the replacement of `null` in the final select:

```
select 
  [AAA] = IsNull([AAA], 0),
  [BBB] = IsNull([BBB], 0)
from 
(
  select [vendid],
    origdocamt 
  from APDoc
) X
pivot
(
  sum(origdocamt) 
  for vendid in ([AAA],[BBB])
) As P
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL`'s you are seeing are because of the new values:

```
select ISNULL([AAA],0) as [AAA], ISNULL([BBB],0) as [BBB]
from 
 (
       select ISNULL([vendid],0)as [vendid],isnull(origdocamt,0)as origdocamt 
        from APDoc
 ) X
pivot
(sum(origdocamt) for vendid in ([AAA],[BBB])) As P
```